What makes a question off topic?
What should determine if a question is marked off topic on this site and what should happen to these questions?

Please read the Tour: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/tour . There, everything you need to know is briefly described. Funny thing, this question is also off-topic, kinda meta haha. It will probably be migrated to meta.cogsci.stackexchange,com

As a new user, you have unfortunately seen some of your posts been scrutinized, put on hold, or even deleted altogether. 
At the time of this writing you haven't received any badges yet on the main site, and for a struggling new user like you it's definitely time to earn the informed badge. All you have to do is go through a quick tour. 
It's going to be especially helpful, in the light of your specific question here, to digest what questions are on topic here in the help center. However, given that your answers were not received well either, please do visit the help section on answering. 
We really welcome new users, but a scientific stack like this does require users to fit in the community's conventions such as, but not limited to:
Questions 

Be specific;
Research before asking;  
Ask valid questions, avoid requests for other users' opinions;  
Allow potential answers to be concise and not ask for wiki-type information;
Ask questions interesting for the community at large.

Answers 

Write science, not personal opinions or anecdotal stories;
Cite credible references or sources;
Elaborate on the key points and avoid one-liners.

